# Resetting username to default on all sites should reset it on stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, profile-page, moderator-tools, stackexchange.com

If I reset a username **and** profile contents to default on one of the sites I moderate, it clears both on the stackexchange.com profile. For example, this is one of the ubiquitous [insurance spammers accounts after resetting](https://stackexchange.com/users/12381215/user2876).

[image: Cleared username and profile content]

But if you don't clear the user profile content, the username reset doesn't make it to stackexchange.com. Last night, a user changed their username to "stackexchange_moderators_suck" I cleared the username but not their profile content, expecting the same behavior but, this morning, I discovered that their profile on stackexchange.com still has the same username.

I did check to see if they'd reset their username after I cleared it, but that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: It depends on whether the user has a registered profile on stackexchange.com itself or not. If they don't, profile changes are automatically synced over from their oldest site profile. If they do, they have to manually sync profile changes. It's that whole messy drop-down menu that never works properly. (Aside: I deleted their stackexchange.com profile so it would sync there.)

Comment: Ah. Interesting. So if our spammer friends start creating SE.com accounts, they won't clear when we clear their profiles :( That's no bueno. For some reason I thought that there was some plan to (re)unify the profiles... eventually. Is that correct?

Comment: The plan was to completely ditch the concept of having a stackexchange.com profile (it's worthless and actually causes a lot of headaches for us - *a lot*) but I don't know whatever happened with that plan.

Comment: So... this is only tangentially related but... if a user doesn't have a stackexchange.com profile... shouldn't deleting both of the user's accounts remove the profile there? For example, Journeyman Geek and I deleted both of the ones from here: https://stackexchange.com/users/12361082/road-tax-prices-co-uk-car-insu?tab=accounts